# Rails New Field Not Appear

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I just got an issue after I've done a migration for a table, I've added owner field to the project table, but it is not appear when I request it (project).

*Expected response after migration:*

```
{
    projects: [
        { id: 1, name: "First proj", owner: 1 },
        { id: 2, name: "Second proj", owner: 1 }
    ]
}
```

*I got:*

```
{
    projects: [
        { id: 1, name: "First proj" },
        { id: 2, name: "Second proj" }
    ]
}
```

**Here is my migration file**

```
class AddOwnerRefToProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        add_reference :projects, :owner, index: true
    end
end
```

**My projects model**

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, :class_name => :User
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the new attribute in your json serializer.

Comment: Thanks @AytanLeibowitz. But sorry, I just begin rails about 2 days ago, where is the the `json serializer`? fyi, I'm using rails 4.

Comment: The path is app > serializers > project_serializer.rb

    `attributes :id, :name, :owner`